# Map 2 interfaces into eachother (example included for understanding)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

in my current project i need to map these 2 interfaces on eachother. Ill get them filled with an api using a service for both (database is the data storage in the backend) and also using ngrx.

```
export interface Plant {
    workplaceId: number;
    orderState: number;
}
```

on

```
export interface OrderStatus {
    orderStateId: number;
    orderStateDesc: string;
}
```

orderState is the same as orderStateId.
`orderState==orderStateId`

Iam not sure where I should do that, since I only need the orderStateDesc to be shown in HTML, which shows the state of the workplace. Not sure if it is understandable, if you don't understand it, just ask further questions please.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your expected input and output?

Comment: there is no input. but the expected output should contain: workplaceId, orderStateDesc. Which will be in real data: 44, "canceled". i want to use it in html like: {{ plant.orderStateDesc }}

Comment: Type-wise, you could simply pick these properties: `type Merged = Omit<Plant, "orderState"> & Omit<OrderStatus, "orderStateId">` (analogue with `Pick`)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new interface

```
export interface EnrichedPlant extends Plant {
  orderStateObj: OrderStatus;
}
```

And you can do something like this:

```
this.enrichedPlants$ = combineLatest([this.plantsService.getAll(), this.orderStatusService.getAll()]).pipe(
  map(([plants, orderStates]) => plants.map(plant => { return {
        ...plant,
        orderStateObj: orderStates.find(orderState => order.orderStateId === plant.orderState)
      };
    })
  ),
);
```

And in html

```
<div *ngFor"let plant of enrichedPlants$ | async">
  orderStateDesc: {{ plant.orderStateObj.orderStateDesc }}
</div>
```